# How to add vertical scrollbar in Angular 9/TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

I have a page where after all the data loaded, the length of the body or the wrapping div is definitely longer than the screen, but no vertical scroll bar is showing.

What is the simplest way to add a vertical scroll bar in Angular 9 after all the XHR are completed? Let the page recompute the length.

Comment: I think you should share the HTML portion to see how to help you.

Comment: I'd say this is more HTML/CSS than Angular. Have you tried setting container's height and set `overflow: auto;` ?

But please share a portion of your code as @mejiajuanbta said so we can have a better context.

Answer (score 0):

Set containers `height: 100vh;` and `overflow: auto;`